# Encryption of a string

Tags: encryption, cryptography

There's a program that encrypts any values. The problem is, I can't understand what the algorithm is.
So, e.g.

input is `1`, output is `cwjtCNNxuYsB+fns/5h66g==`

input is `2`, output is `UR/EJ8GNC/eG5zFXBwbXDw==` and so on.

When the input becomes bigger, the output becomes bigger as well:

input `London is the capital of Great Britain`, output `mnmxU29GVF+e+zn6Y8k246TdbF3wafzl7/ohdgA9KEvZNoLG02JW5HdcwZJNiZmA`.

The strange things here are these "+", "/" and "=".

I can't understand how to classify such cipher.

Comment: The output is encoded with base64. You may deduce that it is a block cipher or not, uses IV or not, however, for the rest, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That output (with the "+", "/" and "=") is `base64` encoding.

`Base64` is an encoding standard that uses a number of ASCII characters to represent binary data, by translating it into a radix-64 representation.

It's widely used to make messages that are encrypted easy to transport over email, WhatsApp, iMessage, etc.

Looking at your examples, they also seem to be encrypted, however, all ciphers will produce larger and larger ciphertext as plaintext input increases.

I expect this is some type of **symmetric block cipher**.

`AES` - the Advanced Encryption Standard, has a block size of 128-bits. Ergo, no matter how small the input (even 1 bit) it will be padded to at least 128-bits. Given that your inputs of '1' and '-2' are in fact encrypted to a 128-bit output, I expect this is likely `AES`.

Indeed "London is the capital of Great Britain" is also a multiple of 128-bits, at 384-bit's of ciphertext.

`mnmxU29GVF+e+zn6Y8k246TdbF3wafzl7/ohdgA9KEvZNoLG02JW5HdcwZJNiZmA`
->

`100110100111100110110001010100110110111101000110010101000101111110011110111110110011100111111010011000111100100100110110111000111010010011011101011011000101110111110000011010011111110011100101111011111111101000100001011101100000000000111101001010000100101111011001001101101000001011000110110100110110001001010110111001000111011101011100110000011001001001001101100010011001100110000000` == `384-bits/128-bit block size` = 3 Blocks of data.

Comment: How big the output size is depends on the mode of operation, even if the block size is static. Of course, if the result size is a multiple of 16 bytes (after decoding) then it is likely that a 16 byte block cipher is used. In this case the result is 48 bytes for an input of  38 bytes, so yeah....

Comment: Good point @MaartenBodewes, also this is a simple implementation that doesn't appear to be appending an IV to the ciphertext...